# How can I obtain more charms in Samurai vs Zombies Defense?

Tags: samurai-vs-zombies

I have noticed that charms can determine if you win or lose when defending your Sacred Gate in Samurai vs Zombies Defense.

On the last selection screen before entering the match, list charms:

- Power Charm
- Lucky Charm
- Friendship Charm
- Wealth Charm
- Haste Charm
- Peace Charm

I seldomly ever get these and the drop almost seems random.  How can I receive more charms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the game everyday (or change your date setting on the device before opening it if you are greedy). You will get a gift each day, like coins, Pachinko balls that you call use to play the Pachinko game in order to get coins and items, wealth charms, sushi, and glu credits. It is not much but you don't need a lot of effort.